# Primefaces Wizard validation problem of input-text fields

Tags: validation, input, text, primefaces, wizard

The wizard does not react to the validation of input fields, although the validation has been set for (p: inputText with required = true). Does anyone have any idea why the wizard ignores the validation?

Note: Validation works if the form is in the tab. If there is a tab in front of the tab with the form, even if there is no content, the validation does not work

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: Not seeing any problems here: https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/panel/wizard.xhtml  Just press Next on the first tab and you get validation failures.